# how to fix undefined symbol for achitecture x86_64 error

Tags: xcode, undefined

This is my main code:

```
#include "startup.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printBanner();                     <-- Undefined symbol for x86_64
readParameters(argc, argv);        <-- Undefined symbol for x86_64
}
```

Contents for startup.h:

```
#ifndef STARTUP_H
#define STARTUP_H

#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void printBanner(void);
void readParameters(const int argc, char *argv[]);

#if defined _cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

The implementations of the above mentioned functions is in startup.c:

```
#include "startup.h"
void readParameters(const int argc, char *argv[]) {
// code
}
void printBanner() {
// code
}
```

All the 3 files are within the same folder. Is there anything that is missing in terms of settings? I'm using xcode for this project. 
I'm calling a function that is defined in .h from my main and the header is included in the .c file where functions are implemented. Can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the `startup.c` file is getting compiled with the other files?

Comment: @AdamH. I've tried look at the output of "preprocess" but it just displays "Unable to Generate Content". Is there any other way of checking if startup.c is getting compiled? Also all files are under same directory. I didn't think anything else would be needed in order for them to build.

Comment: Check that the file is listed in your compile sources.

Comment: @AdamH. Thanks for the tip. My file was not showing up in compile sources. Updated so that it now appears and errors disappear. Thank you :)